# How can I mark up text to be skipped by Google Translate?

Tags: google-translate

I have placed a Google Translate widget on my site, but want certain elements (resource names and addresses on a resource list) to remain untranslated, while the descriptions *are* translated.

Is there some way to mark those items up so that Google Translate skips them?

Comment: Stick around, as the answer _might_ take a few moments (days).

Comment: I have been Googling, but not finding an answer

Comment: I found the answer, for anyone else who might be looking. You just add the class "notranslate" to your element and Google Translate will leave it untranslated.

Ref: https://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en#2641276

Comment: please post as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, for anyone else who might be looking. You just add the class "notranslate" to your element and Google Translate will leave it untranslated.

Ref: [support.google.com/translate/?hl=en#2641276](http://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en#2641276)

Comment: Google Translate Help article was removed. The only other reference that I found is https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_translate.asp